# Rails - Editing bootstrap progress bars in the "edit" and "new" action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have a rails app with a `Project` Model, and I would like to know how can I make it possible so that a User can edit the percentage of a bootstrap progress bar by going to the edit page for that model. I found a gem that will generate the code to show the progress bars in rails, but I have no idea how to allow the user to edit that progress bar and have a unique progress bar for every new `Project` in the database. What kind of input field would I need and how would I link it to the progress bar?

This is the code to generate the progress bar from the rails-bootstrap-progressbar gem:

```
<%= progress_bar 0.6 %>
```

Documentation for that gem: https://github.com/spacewander/rails-bootstrap-progressbar

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done by looking at the exact method you want to change.

You need the `progress_bar` helper method inside this file.

https://github.com/spacewander/rails-bootstrap-progressbar/blob/master/lib/bootstrap_progressbar/helper.rb#L62

Lucky for you the author of the gem added options to the method.
As you can see in this piece of code

```
  def progress_bar(percent, options = {})
    Private.check_percent(percent)

    clazz = [options.delete(:class), 'progress'].join(' ').strip()
    id = " id='#{options.delete(:id)}' " if options[:id]
    style = " style='#{options.delete(:style)}' " if options[:style]
    ...
  end
```

You can modify how the progressbar looks by changing the `class, id or style` attribute.

Example:

```
<%= progress_bar 0.6, class: "mycustomclass", id: "mycustomid", style: "color: red" %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you literally need something completely different then the original I would advise to actually write your own helper method to do so. 

You can copy paste part of the authors code.

The benefit is that you will know and understand how to write proper helper methods.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. But what im trying to do exactly is make it possible for a user to edit the % of the progress bar, so I need to somehow integrate it into the edit form page of the Project model. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Do you want to change how the percentage looks in bootstrap slider?
or
Do you want to make the value inside the slider change?

Comment: I need to be able to change the value of the slider so that the user can update it. so using the example above i need the user to be able to change <%= progress_bar 0.6 %> to <%= progress_bar 0.8 %> for example, directly in the "edit" page. I dont want to change the way it looks, just be able to change the state its in in terms of percentage and how full the bar appears.

Comment: This is typically done just by changing the value property of the slider with javascript. You may want to take a look at a javascript solution for bootstrap sliders. As you want to change the value dynamically. https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

Comment: Thanks alot il check it out and let you know if it worked!